# Identifying the model of Moen faucet in kitchen

Tags: kitchens, leak, faucet

**EDIT**

[**Here is a following-up question about disassembling this faucet**](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/220992/disassembling-a-faucet-to-replace-its-catridge)

**END EDIT**

My kitchen sink faucet is leaky at the base and it should be able to be fixed by replacing cartridge according to online tutorials.

Although the maker, MOEN, can be identified, no model number can be found. Could anybody identify the model?

Or should I just disassemble everything and bring them to Home depot or Lowe's for help?

[image: Full picture]

[image: Base of the faucet]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or should I just disassemble everything and bring them to Home depot
> or Lowe's for help?

Yes, take the cartridge to Lowes and look for a match.

If you can not find a match then go to a plumbing supply house.

Comment: Try bring the picture to the True Value hardware store, if there is one near by. The service staffs are quit experienced on plumbing hardware, and supplies. I just did it this morning, but the one I went ran out of Moen faucet though.

Comment: Will try that when they open again tomorrow. I went to a home depot which is close to me, and the staff I encountered seems not so experienced on plumbing hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Call Moen at the service number on their website. Their support is very knowledgeable and helpful, and will likely mail you a replacement part for free if you are covered under their warranty.

Comment: Will try. Thanks for the information.

Comment: All the faucets in the 2 houses that I have built and owned had Moen  in them. All the replacement parts so far have been warranted with their lifetime warranty program to the original owner.

Comment: I would not have used their products though, if I had choices. First, their products are not of the best quality - I have had various problems with their products. Second, their seivice number is very hard to call - I tried, and a robot on the phone suggested a call back three days later, or one week later.