# Removing a decorative cover in a moen faucet

Tags: faucet

After [taking the handle off a faucet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/220992/disassembling-a-faucet-to-replace-its-cartridge), the decorative cover won't come off. I tried a strap wrentch first, then a pipe wrenth. Is there any trick for this? I don't care if it is going to damage the chrome surface - after having applied a pipe wrentch, I think I need to replace the cover any way :(

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/293889), what is it you are actually attempting to do? Generally, one doesn't actually "remove" the housing (or even parts of it), one puts a wrench or socket on the cartridge in the middle and removes it from the housing. That's likely just chrome plating on the brass housing and _won't_ come apart without serious destruction.

Comment: Probably I am in the trap. Ugh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That piece could be press fitted into the valve body and heavily corroded but since the cartridge screw is accessible with just the handle being removed (unusual), try removing it. Never use a pipe wrench on chrome. Even if you could remove it now, you'd never find a replacement unless you lucked out at a plumbing supply store.

Comment: The nut size is 7/8 inches. If the cover is not removed (or not removable), then a nut driver of that size is needed - I am trying to find one from home depot.

Comment: Removed the retainer nut of plastic with my car whell lug nut wrench :)

Comment: @sofname  Now you're getting the hang of DIY.  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting the hang of DIY. :-)